# How to display fullscreen image from viewpager as small image in gridview?

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-gridview

I followed this link http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-implementing-viewpager-into-gridview-tutorial/ to obtain gridview in viewpager. But my problem is that the image displayed as full screen in viewpager appear to be cut in gridview window. I want the image that appear as full screen should also appear in gridview window. In other words, the image displayed as full screen should appear as whole in  small size image in gridview window.I meant something like the images displayed in this question link...[Order of images in Grid View in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716570/order-of-images-in-grid-view-in-android)

I just start with programming, so please give some explanations, or it will be great if you also give some codes :)

Comment: Download the sample app at: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at [`ImageView.ScaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). It it will show you how the image should be scaled, cropped, etc. to be displayed in an `ImageView`.